# Need to combine two functions into one (Python)

Tags: python, function, recursion

Here is my code-

```
def Max(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        m = Max(lst[1:])
        if m > lst[0]: 
            return m
        else:
            return lst[0]
def Min(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        m = Min(lst[1:])
        if m < lst[0]: 
            return m
        else:
            return lst[0]
print("Max number:",Max([5,4,100,0,2]))
print("Min number:",Min([5,4,100,0,2]))
```

Basically I need a single function that returns both the largest and smallest number and it needs to be recursively. How would would I change this code?

Comment: Have you tried anything? A regular loop with two parameters for min and max would do the trick

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing forum. What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: You could just write a function that returns `Max(lst), Min(lst)`.  It will be inefficient since it will recurse twice, but it's the simplest way to combine the two existing functions.

Comment: Use objects! Your object can have 2 properties min and max. Keep updating both based on your condition!

Answer (score 6):

Some types of recursive algorithms/implementations operating on a list input are <del>very</del> quite easy to come up with, if you know the "trick". That trick being:

> **Just assume you already have a function that can do what you want.**

Wait, no, that **doesn't really make sense**, does it? Then we'd already be done.

Let's try that again:

> **Just assume you already have a function that can do what you want** (but *only* for inputs 1 element smaller than you need)**.**

There, much better. While a bit silly, that's an assumption we can work with.

So what *do* we want? In your example, it's returning the minimum and maximum elements of a list. Let's assume we want them returned as a 2-tuple (a.k.a. a "pair"):

```
lst = [5, 4, 100, 0, 2]

# Well, actually, we can only do this for a smaller list,
# as per our assumption above.
lst = lst[1:]

lst_min, lst_max = magic_min_max(lst)  # I want a pony!

assert lst_min == 0   # Wishful thinking
assert lst_max == 100 # Wishful thinking
```

If we have such a magic function, can we use it to solve the problem for the actual input size? Let's try:

```
def real_min_max(lst):
    candidate = lst[0]
    rest_of_the_list = lst[1:]
    min_of_rest, max_of_rest = magic_min_max(rest_of_the_list) # Allowed because
                                                               # smaller than lst
    min_of_lst = candidate if candidate < min_of_rest else min_of_rest
    max_of_lst = candidate if candidate > max_of_rest else max_of_rest
    return min_of_lst, max_of_lst
```

Not exactly easy, but pretty straight forward, isn't it? **But let's assume our magic function `magic_min_max` has an additional restriction: It cannot handle empty lists.** (After all, an empty list doesn't *have* neither a minimum nor a maximum element. Not even *magic* can change that.)

So if `lst` has size 1, we must not call the magic function. No problem for us, though. That case is easy to detect *and* easy to circumvent. The single element is both minimum and maximum of its list, so we just return it twice:

```
def real_min_max(lst):
    candidate = lst[0]
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return candidate, candidate  # single element is both min & max
    rest_of_the_list = lst[1:]
    min_of_rest, max_of_rest = magic_min_max(rest_of_the_list) # Allowed because
                                                               # smaller than lst
                                                               # but (if we get
                                                               # here) not empty
    min_of_lst = candidate if candidate < min_of_rest else min_of_rest
    max_of_lst = candidate if candidate > max_of_rest else max_of_rest
    return min_of_lst, max_of_lst
```

So that's that.

But wait ... **there is no magic**. If we want to call a function, it has to actually exist. So we need to implement a function that can return the minimum and maximum of a list, so we can call it in `real_min_max` instead of `magic_min_max`. As this is about recursion, you know the solution: `real_min_max` *is* that function (once it's fixed by calling a function that *does* exist) so we can have it call itself:

```
def real_min_max(lst):
    candidate = lst[0]
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return candidate, candidate  # single element is both min & max
    rest_of_the_list = lst[1:]
    min_of_rest, max_of_rest = real_min_max(rest_of_the_list) # No magic needed,
                                                              # just recursion!
    min_of_lst = candidate if candidate < min_of_rest else min_of_rest
    max_of_lst = candidate if candidate > max_of_rest else max_of_rest
    return min_of_lst, max_of_lst
```

Let's try it:

```
lst = [5, 4, 100, 0, 2]
real_min_max(lst)  # returns (0, 100)
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys


class MaxMin:
  max = -sys.maxint - 1
  min = sys.maxint

  def getMaxMin(self, lst, obj):
      if len(lst) == 1:
          obj.max = lst[0]
          obj.min = lst[0]
      else:
          self.getMaxMin(lst[1:], obj)
          if obj.max < lst[0]: 
              obj.max = lst[0]
          if obj.min > lst[0]: 
              obj.min = lst[0]

obj = MaxMin()
obj.getMaxMin([5,4,100,0,2], obj)
print("Max number:",obj.max)
print("Min number:",obj.min)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the exact idea of *higher order functions*. You can add a `compare` parameter in your function, and pass `lambda a, b: a>b` for `Min` and `lambda a, b: a < b` for max. then, instead of `m > lst[0]`, use `compare(m, lst[0])`