# Returning the sum of all nodes in a tree through recursion

Tags: python, recursion, huffman-code

I have created an algorithm for Huffman coding that creates the Huffman tree for a given set of symbols, and their pmf. My alogrithm uses my own `Node` class which has the instance variables `string symbol`, `float probability`, `list children`, `string code`.

I can iterate through my tree recursively as follows:

```
def print_codes(root):
    for child in root.children:                             # Iterate through children
        if (child.symbol):                                  # If node isn't a blank node
            print(child.symbol + " = " + child.code)        # print its original symbol and code
        if (child.children):                                # If node has children
            print_codes(child)                              # print their codes recursively
```

Each parent node is a blank node, and each leaf node contains one of the symbols of the albhabet I am encoding. If I wanted to find the total sum of the lengths of each node's code (only the nodes where `node.symbol == True`, how could I achieve this in my recursive function? Where would I return from each recursive call?

Comment: Try to apply the approach from http://stackoverflow.com/a/42147213/674064 . Instead of "input 1 element smaller" assume a tree one level less deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to test without data, but this should bring you closer to your goal:

```
def recursive_len_sum(node):
    temp = 0
    if node.symbol:
        temp += len(node.code)
    for child in node.children:
        temp += recursive_len_sum(child)
    return temp

recursive_len_sum(root)
```